# Migrations (Entity Framework 4.3) - script doesn't get executed

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

The scripts are generated correctly, i use multiple layers so the following commands are run into the Package Manager Console

Eg. When i added Email column to the table : "Owner"

```
Add-Migration AddEmailToOwner -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose
```

--> Result:

```
Using NuGet project 'FacturatieMVCv2.Data'.
Target database is: 'FacturatieMVCv2.Data.Website.MyResellerContext' (DataSource: V-File   \SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
```

Next command i use is:

```
Update-Database -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose
```

--> Result:

```
Using NuGet project 'FacturatieMVCv2.Data'.
Target database is: 'FacturatieMVCv2.Data.Website.MyResellerContext' (DataSource: V-FILE\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
Applying explicit migrations: [201203080906140_AddDamnToOwner].
Applying explicit migration: 201203080906140_AddDamnToOwner.
ALTER TABLE [Owners] ADD [Damn] [nvarchar](max)
[Inserting migration history record]
```

My connectionstring in the App.Config is :

```
<parameter value="Server=V-FILE\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ProductionReseller;uid=sa;password=n*****3;" />
```

Although i specified the Initial catalog, it is targetting the wrong catalog. It's created / updated the database table named: FacturatieMVCv2.Data.Website.MyResellerContext .

Following is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
        <!--<parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />-->
        <parameter  value="Server=V-FILE02\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ProductionReseller;uid=sa;password=12345678;" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

In short, the Update-Database command, updated the wrong database.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following command:

```
Update-Database -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=V-FILE\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ProductionReseller;uid=mydbuser;password=mydbpass;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlConnectionFactory` adds the Initial Catalog to the value you provide. If you want to use a specific connection string for a context, you should add an entry in the `connectionStrings` section instead. E.g.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyResellerContext" connectionString="Server=V-FILE\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ProductionReseller;uid=sa;password=12345678;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Already tried that before my solution, but it gives an error in App.Config and in combination with migrations ;)

Answer (score 0):

We store config variables in build configs to switch between these and ran into this issue; the solution was to Clean then explicitly Build.

To expand on that:

Our Db class (the one that inherits DbContext) has a Constructor like:

```
    public Db()
#if AltDb
        : base("AltDb")
#else
        : base("Db")
#endif
    {
    }
```

So if the AltDb build var is defined, it's going to use the ConnectionString named AltDb; otherwise it uses the one named Db. In our Project configs, we have one named AltDb and all it does is define the AltDb build variable.

So we have those 2 connection strings defined in Web.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Db" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyProj;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS...
    <add name="AltDb" connectionString="Initial Catalog=Staging;Data Source...
```

So, when we want to update the alternate db, we SHOULD be able to just switch build configs and run update-database. This has worked in every project for years, but today it just wouldn't.

When I ran a Clean, then made sure this build config was selected and the startup Project was selected, and explicitly Built, magically it was solved - even though EF appears to build everything every time you run update-database.

I have no explanation as to why this would occur, but that's the cause and solution for us.